# No vmhgfs-fuse command in CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, vmware, vmware-fusion

I've installed open-vm-tools in CentOS 7, but how can I mount shared folder?

There's no `vmhgfs-fuse` command, and `mount -t vmhgfs .host:/ /mnt/` shows an error `unknown file system vmhgfs`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CentOS 7.2 includes a 3.10 kernel, and open-vm-tools 9.10. A [4.x kernel and open-vm-tools version 10 are required to use the FUSE support provided by open-vm-tools](https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools/blob/master/ReleaseNotes.md). As a result, it is still necessary to install the traditional tar format VMware Tools to add the vmhgfs driver to enable shared folder support. This should be done alongside the existing open-vm-tools installation.

More details:

- http://partnerweb.vmware.com/GOSIG/CentOS_7.html
- https://github.com/chef/bento/issues/667